# How can I recognize peaches with split pits?

Tags: fruit, ingredient-selection

Split pits in stone fruit can be a [real problem for farmers](http://www.abc.net.au/news/rural/2016-11-16/peaches-split-from-weather/8030296), because fruit that are seriously affected can’t be sold. However, if the damage isn’t obvious from the outside, the fruit are going to the stores just as usual.

For me as a consumer and cook, split pit peaches and nectarines are in the best case a nuisance because they need a bit more work than normal fruit, in the worst case, there will be mold on the inside of the pit that also infects the flesh.

[image]

**Is there a way to recognize peaches or nectarines with a split pit before cutting them open? Preferably at the store?**

Comment: When picking fresh, fruit with split pits will often be weeping for the spot under the spine of the pit, or around the step.  This is not and answer trough as it is not 100%, and not all the them weeping even have the issue, plus most of these have been sorted out before they go to market so this would only marginally help and mostly when picking, not shopping.

Comment: I've also encountered this problem often. My guess is that if there was a practical reliable way either people would avoid them, or the producers would be forced to remove them

Answer (score 1):

This problem is made by flies, they lay eggs inside fruit. The end where the stem is you can see a scab with long puckering, avoid these. Go to a different seller, or tell farmer to put out fake red apples with sticky stuff on them when the flowers are out this will attract the flies and catch them and save their fruit from damage